# cloud endpoints return error 401 unauthorized request

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

So i have made a few cloud endpoints to be used in an application and am going through the process of securing them in an android client. Everytime i try and consume data in the android client code, i get error 401 "Unautorized Access". I can tell why the exception is being thrown as i am nullchecking the 'User' parameter on every api method. But my question is why i am always getting a null User for my api methods. I have successfully given my endpoint builder the correct credentials and setSelectedAccountName with the account on the phone. here is my example:

One api method:

```
 public CollectionResponse<Student> getAllStudents(User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
        if (user == null)
               throw new OAuthRequestException("BAD_USER");
        else {
               List<Student> stud = ofy().load().type(Student.class).list();
               return CollectionResponse.<Student>builder().setItems(stud).build();
           }
    }
```

this is placed at the top of the api as well:

```
@Api(name = "studentEndpoint", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "appbackend.mymodule.example.com", ownerName = "appbackend.mymodule.example.com", packagePath=""),
            scopes = {Constants.EMAIL},
            clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID},
            audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE})
```

I am grabbing the account email using account manager in my android client, setting up credentials and getting an access token.

```
GoogleAccountCredential cred = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(AddUser.this, AppConstants.AUDIENCE);
                cred.setSelectedAccountName(emailAccount);
```

this is how i am using it in my client code:

```
StudentEndpoint service = AppConstants.getApiHandle(cred);
                stud = service.getAllStudents().execute();
```

The above code is being called asynchronously.

I have triple checked my client ids to make sure they are correct and they are. I am also installing this from android studio directly onto my phone via adb. I have my debug SHA1 in the the google cloud console, but do i need my release SHA1 there as well. I didnt think i would because i have not created release keys for this app yet and have only used an unsigned copy. As well if i use the web-client I can authenticate but everytime i make a request i get error 401, and i see my exception 'BAD_USER' thrown. I do have a 'Bearer' key tho showing that i have access.

If i cancel the nullcheck on the User parameter in my module the methods work fine and i can get the data from my datastore. So any reason why i am getting a null user everytime i make api requests? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to revisit the following 3 points:

- Make sure that your package name is correct i.e. same in both the Android app and the package name that was specified when creating the credentials in the Cloud Console.
- Can you check the value of the `AppConstants.AUDIENCE` in your code. Ideally it needs to be in the following format "server:client_id:WEB_CLIENT_ID'
- Ensure that your `Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID` is the same as `Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE`

Comment: Thank you, i feel stupid for not noticing this but i had my Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE="WEB_CLIENT_ID" instead of =WEB_CLIENT_ID....this makes it work on an android device but i am still getting error 401 in the web client